# Binding change not pushed back to gui

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have the following code somewhere (using C# and UWP):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SupportsFineChannelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SupportsFineChannel", typeof(bool), typeof(ChannelGroupView),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

public bool SupportsFineChannel {
    get { return (bool) GetValue(SupportsFineChannelProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SupportsFineChannelProperty, value); }
}
```

and in my gui I use it with

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FineChannel, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding SupportsFineChannel, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SupportsFineChannel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Supports Fine Channel</CheckBox>
```

Now I have a (for my understanding) unusual behaviour. If I load the frame while the `SupportFineChannel` is false, the Textbox is disabled. Check. If I do the same while the bool is true, the Textbox is enabled. Check, binding works.

Now the strange part is that the TextBox won't change its IsEnabled value if I change it trough the checkbox.

With the debugger I confirmed:

- The Evaluated Binding value of the CheckBox gets changed
- The binding properly propagates to the Variable in the backend which changes as expected
- The evaluated textbox binding value though does not take note of the changed DepProp.

I have set the binding to OneWay and TwoWay, both do not alter this behaviour. Why does the DepProp not propagate the change back to the bindings?

**EDIT**
I just tested it with different properties. Fact is, no dependency property pushes values back to the gui when it changes... srsly?

**EDIT2**
INotifyPropertyChanged does work though.. Is there some different behaviour with DepProps on UWP that I'm not aware of?

**EDIT3**
It was easier than I thought to create a repro sample. So nothing crazy with my setups..
For anyone interested, [here it is](http://lumenliquid.net/public/DepPropBug.zip).

In case the link goes down sometime or you don't trust me;

1. I created a new UWP blank project with target version 10.0, 15063, Min Version 10.0 10586
2. Create a DataView and a ItemView

   ```
   public class DataView : DependencyObject {
       public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemStuffProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           "ItemStuff", typeof(ObservableCollection<ItemView>), typeof(DataView),
           new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<ItemView>)));

       public ObservableCollection<ItemView> ItemStuff {
           get { return (ObservableCollection<ItemView>) GetValue(ItemStuffProperty); }
           set { SetValue(ItemStuffProperty, value); }
       }

       public DataView() {
           ItemStuff = new ObservableCollection<ItemView>();
       }
   }

   public class ItemView : DependencyObject {
       public static readonly DependencyProperty SupportsStuffProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           "SupportsStuff", typeof(bool), typeof(ItemView), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

       public bool SupportsStuff {
           get { return (bool) GetValue(SupportsStuffProperty); }
           set { SetValue(SupportsStuffProperty, value); }
       }

       public static readonly DependencyProperty TextStuffProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           "TextStuff", typeof(string), typeof(ItemView), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

       public string TextStuff {
           get { return (string) GetValue(TextStuffProperty); }
           set { SetValue(TextStuffProperty, value); }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the DataView and an example Item to your codebehind

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "Data", typeof(DataView), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataView)));

   public DataView Data {
       get { return (DataView) GetValue(DataProperty); }
       set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
   }


   public MainPage() {
       Data=new DataView();
       Data.ItemStuff.Add(new ItemView());
       this.InitializeComponent();
   }
   ```
4. Set your Datacontext to `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Data}"`
5. Add your Listbox

   ```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemStuff}">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding TextStuff}" IsEnabled="{Binding SupportsStuff, Mode=OneWay}" />
                   <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SupportsStuff, Mode=TwoWay}"> Supports Stuff</CheckBox>
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
   ```
6. ???
7. Profit!

Comment: Mode=TwoWay on IsEnabled?  Think about that for a sec.  Not sure if that's the cause, tho.

Comment: I also tried OneWay. Technically it shouldn't make a difference as the user can't change that value.

Comment: Change `Binding` to `x:Bind`, would that make a difference?

Comment: I can't use it here as this is an itemtemplate for a listbox and x:bind would bind to the code behind instead of the item.

Comment: Is it possible you can share a sample repro?

Comment: Reproducing it was easier than I thought. Have "fun" exploring this behaviour.

Comment: Why not to use *INotifyPropertyChanged*?

Comment: This looks like one limitation in WinRT as I'd assume such should work in WPF. But I guess they took it out for performance reasons. It looks to me that *dependency properties* in UWP will only notify the UI about property updates **within** its *owner*.

But what you are doing is assigning control objects (e.g. `DependencyObject`) to other control objects (e.g. `TextBox`). This is neither efficiency nor recommended.

I'd refactor your code and turn the `ItemView` into a proper `UserControl` which contains the `TextBox` & the `CheckBox`. I don't see much point to even have the `DataView`.

Comment: @Romasz now I do. I changed everything which works fine. But I'd still  like a doc of what's going on though

Comment: A DataView is needed for proper MVVM though. But it indeed works when the collection is part of the code behind.